# how can I download my file residing in local repository

Tags: php, csv, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

I am new to CodeIgniter and was working on downloading a file. However, I want to download a file that resides on my local machine, I am able to locate the file by providing the path, also the file gets downloaded with a `File` type, However, I want my file to be in `.csv`  format

Here goes my Controller's download function:

```
public function download()
{   
        $state_id=$this->input->post('state'); // gets me the state-id from viw's dropdown
        $this->load->helper('download'); // Load download helper
        $file="C:\\Users\usernew\\Desktop\\New folder\\".$state_id.".csv";
        $filename=$state_id.'.csv';
        
    
        if (file_exists($file))
        {
                $data = file_get_contents($file);       //check file exists 
                force_download($fileName,$data);
            }
            else{
                echo"not working!";
            }    
        }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `force_download()` takes in two parameters, i.e. the file name and the data to be written to that file. As the file already consists of some sample data, therefore, the function goes like this:

```
 public function download()
{   
        $state_id=$this->input->post('state'); // gets me the state-id from viw's dropdown
        $this->load->helper('download'); // Load download helper
        $filename=$state_id.'.csv';
        $file="C:\\Users\usernew\\Desktop\\New folder\\".$filename;
        
        
    
        if (file_exists($file))                    //check file exists
        {
                force_download($file,NULL);      //NULL as the file already has data
            }
            else{
                echo"not working!";
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use header function instead force_download:

```
$file="C:\\Users\usernew\\Desktop\\New folder\\".$state_id.".csv";
$filename=$state_id.'.csv';

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
readfile( $file );
```

Comment: @parshanr the above code runs fine and will download the file with the intended name, but the issue will be that it explicitly creates a new file with no data in it, so the file downloaded has no data stored in it. refer the answere: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66621956/11635281